# display website page on Facebook tab

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to display any given page from a 3rd party website on a Facebook page tab? (Using iframe / fbml)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use iFrames to load content from 'certain' websites/pages, given that they support POST requests.

This tutorial on FB Documentation has more information.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

http://apps.facebook.com/iframe-apps/?ref=ts

Answer (score 0):

No, Just FBML pages are allowed for tab page, also not all FBML tags(exp. iframe and fb:iframe are disabled).

Comment: Is this still the case? AFAICS, FBML is now deprecated, and IFRAMEs are the preferred way to do tabs.